# Suppress warnings from dependencies with Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Assuming I have a `Package.swift` like this below, and `SomePackage` from the dependencies produces warnings during `swift build`.

```swift
// swift-tools-version:4.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "my-app",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://some-package.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.0"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["SomePackage"]
    ]
)
```

How can I suppress those warnings from the dependencies, but keep the ones coming from my code?

Comment: I'm using a custom script based on CocoaPods' `xcodeproj` tool which I run after generating my Xcode project. See: https://gist.github.com/siemensikkema/57ef1ce3340e32b72dc59e44bc37b477 I adjust it to make exceptions for the frameworks that are generating warnings that I don't care about (in my case when working with Vapor 2).

Answer (score 8):

With Swift Tools Version 5 you may define compiler flags in the package file (see https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html#swiftsetting). Here is an example for a `Package.swift` which suppresses compiler warnings during build:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Antlr4",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Antlr4",
            targets: ["Antlr4"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Antlr4",
            dependencies: [],
            swiftSettings: [
                .unsafeFlags(["-suppress-warnings"]),
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "Antlr4Tests",
            dependencies: ["Antlr4"]),
    ]
)
```

To suppress warnings only in foreign code you should split the code into two packages.

Comment: Tried this one out but didn't work for `found 1 file(s) which are unhandled; explicitly declare them as resources or exclude from the target`.
XCode group those warnings as uncategorized can this be the reason why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 5):

For Objective-C modules, you can use the following to disable all warnings:

```
cSettings: [
   .unsafeFlags(["-w"])
]
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't know how to suppress only dependencies warnings but it is possible to suppress all warnings during build by passing this option: `-Xswiftc -suppress-warnings`. The call will looks like

```
swift build -Xswiftc -suppress-warnings
```

Comment: Partway solution, like either get all warnings or get none. Thanks.

Comment: The question is how to suppress warnings on _dependencies_. So, the answer is not to suppress _all_ warnings.

Comment: Actually something I was looking for. What would be the equivalent for xodeubild?

Answer (score -6):

If you are using an **Xcode 10** project file:

1. Click the project file in Xcode
2. Select the target of your dependency
3. Go to Build Settings
4. Search for **Swift Compiler - Warnings Policies**
5. Set the **Suppress Warnings** flags appropriately

Comment: In my opinion this way is the most correct and easy.

Comment: The question is how to suppress warnings on _dependencies_. So, the answer is not to suppress _all_ warnings.