# Xcode 12 IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET warning for SPM dependencies

Tags: xcode, swift5, swift-package-manager, xcode12

After updating to Xcode 12, I've got lots of warnings for SPM dependencies (including RxSwift and Facebook).

> The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99.

Can I suppress these warnings somehow, or is the only way to wait till the creators of appropriate frameworks fixed it?

Comment: For cocoapods, setting `SWIFT_SUPPRESS_WARNINGS` to `YES` works. There might be a similar thing for SPM or a build script perhaps. Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019781/667586

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
@available(iOS, deprecated: 9.0)
```

or this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
```